# How to change the new TabLayout indicator color and height

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I was playing around with the new `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`, and found a problem, in the class definition, there are no methods to change the indicator color, and default height.

Doing some research, found that the default indicator color is taken from the AppTheme. Specifically from here:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
```

Now, in my case, if I change the `colorAccent`, it will affect all the other views which uses this value as background color, for example ProgressBar

Now is there any way to change the indicatorColor to other thing besides the `colorAccent`?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Having the problem that the new TabLayout uses the indicator color from the value `colorAccent`, I decided to dig into the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` implementation, finding that there are no public methods to customize this. However I found this style specification of the TabLayout:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Having this style specification, now we can customize the TabLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/pages_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
```

And problem solved, both the tab indicator color and height can be changed from their default values.

Comment: is there a way change the 'tabSelectedTextColor' (Not tabindicator color or height) via java code.

Comment: the app:tabIndicatorColor attribute in the tabLayout xml widget is the only change I needed to make to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I made this as parent style: `parent="@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout"`

Comment: This solution founds to be legit

Answer (score 118):

With the design support library you can now change them in the xml:

To change the **color** of the TabLayout indicator:

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color"
```

To change the **height** of the TabLayout indicator:

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
```

Comment: I put this line, but color is still accent color

Comment: @Kenji are you sure that this line was put in the TabLayout and not in the Toolbar bit of the xml? Easy misplacement to make :)

Comment: Perfect solution for height. It works fine. Thanks Malek.

Comment: What if i want to apply a gradient color instead?

Answer (score 37):

Since I can't post a follow-up to [android developer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height/32082705#comment52039760_30908854), here's an updated answer for anyone else who needs to programmatically set the selected tab indicator color:

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Similarly, for height:

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (2 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

These methods were only recently added to [revision 23.0.0 of the Support Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html), which is why [Soheil Setayeshi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height/30908854#30908854) uses reflection.

Comment: setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight is deprecated now, any idea what to use now?

Answer (score 19):

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 14):

With the **desing support library v23** you can set programmatically the color and the height.

**Just use for the height:**

```
TabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int height)
```

Here the [official javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int)).

**Just use for the color:**

```
TabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int color)
```

Here the [official javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int)).

Here you can find the info in the [Google Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175182&can=1&q=label%3AVersion-Support-23&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Comment: What integers are we supposed to use for color?

Comment: You can use the Color class for example Color.RED

Comment: setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight is deprecated now

Answer (score 9):

To change indicator color and height programmatically you can use reflection. for example for indicator color use code below:

```
        try {
            Field field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mTabStrip");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object ob = field.get(tabLayout);
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$SlidingTabStrip");
            Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("setSelectedIndicatorColor", int.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(ob, Color.RED);//now its ok
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and to change indicator height use "setSelectedIndicatorHeight" instead of "setSelectedIndicatorColor" then invoke it by your desired height

Comment: Thank you! this helps me! I guess Google forgot to provide method for this in their support library.

Comment: Why use reflection, if it's already available as public functions?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int)

Comment: @SoheilSetayeshi Oh, ok. Thank you. Maybe you should update the answer then.

Comment: But this is a perfect solution for APIs below support library 23.0.0. I mean Whaao! Great Answer!

Answer (score 9):

from xml :

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
```

from java :

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (2 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

Answer (score 6):

Foto indicator use this:

```
 tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorWhite));//put your color
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this using xml

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line in your code. If you change the color then change the color value in parentheses.

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Android makes it easy.

```
public void setTabTextColors(int normalColor, int selectedColor) {
    setTabTextColors(createColorStateList(normalColor, selectedColor));
}
```

So, we just say

```
mycooltablayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#1464f4"), Color.parseColor("#880088"));
```

That will give us a blue normal color and purple selected color.

Now we set the height

```
public void setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int height) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorHeight(height);
}
```

And for height we say

```
mycooltablayout.setSelectedIndicatorHeight(6);
```

Comment: this is only works for the textcolor, not the tab backround

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `app:tabIndicator=""` to set indicator, and using a `layer-list` drawable as your **custom indicator**, then you'd better to set `app:tabIndicatorColor=""` together, because i see this in the source code of TabLayout:

[TabLayout.SlidingTabIndicator#draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXVVP.png)

**If you don't set `app:tabIndicatorColor=""`**, then the custom indicator will be drawn with your `colorPrimary` or `colorAccent` as the tint color