# android.support.design.widget.tablayout Tab Indicator colour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I am using TabLayout and a View Pager to show multiple tabs. I want to change the selected tab indicator. I have used `app:tabIndicatorColor`but the colour is not changing. It shows a greenish colour. I have read that by default the tabIndicator colour is set to`color/accent`, however the greenish colour is not my accent colour.
My xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/primary_light" 
/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    />
```

What am I missing?
Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrhk9.jpg

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height

Comment: @EranBoudjnah I have already tried that solution. The answer there is exactly my code above.

Comment: Have you tried one of the solutions suggesting you change it programmatically?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

It can help You.

```
 app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"  here is the line which change the color.
```

Comment: In case you didn't go through the code originally posted, I have already tried  `app:tabIndicatorColor`

Comment: What if you want to change gravity of the indicator?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following customization for your `TabLayout`,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/pages_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
```

This should solve the indicator color!

Comment: how can we set it in java?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of TabLayout, the tabTextColor must reference a selector color instead of a single color. This is the part in the source code where it uses `getColorStateList`:

```
if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.TabLayout_tabTextColor)) {
    // If we have an explicit text color set, use it instead
    mTabTextColors = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TabLayout_tabTextColor);
}
```

so you should define your colors in file like this for example `res/color/your_colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:color=""@color/primary_light"/>
    <item android:color="#0000ff"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set color Programmatically like

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(R.color.black);
```