# How can I change the color of at the bottom of a tabview implemented with fragments

Tags: android, tabview

I want to change the color of bottom of a tabview ( Its is blue by default but I want to change it to red ).

I have put an image of my application :
[image: this is the image]

And by the way I'm not using android support in my application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the new TabLayout indicator color and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height)

Comment: No mine is different if u look at the source

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)

   {tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);}   tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.color.tab_selected);}
```

Comment: I haven't implemented the menu with TabHost I have used a framelayout and fragement

Comment: Download it from here :  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01306559512437422437

Comment: try this http://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/