# Get Android default Tab indicator color

Tags: android, xml

I was trying to make a tricky layout for which i need the Android's default tab indicator color.

I have searched a lot but every where I find how to change and customize tab indicator but could not find how to get color code in hex of default tab indicator.

Comment: U mean, TabLayout from android.support.design.widget??

Comment: I think you should follow following site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height

Comment: Yes the design widget, the link you refereed shows how to change the color of indicator, I don't want to do that, I want to get the color as a hexadecimal value.

Comment: You want that value programatically?

Comment: Programatically and in XML both !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research for your question, I hope this will help you.

The tab indicator color is set in the Inner Class `SlidingTabStrip` of the class [TabLayout (Code)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java?autodive=0%2F%2F). Sadly you can't access this variable.

```
private class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    // ...

    void setSelectedIndicatorColor(int color) {
        if (mSelectedIndicatorPaint.getColor() != color) {
            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }
}
```

But in a constructor of the `TabLayout` the default tab indicator color is set.

```
public TabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    // Add the TabStrip
    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TabLayout, defStyleAttr, R.style.Widget_Design_TabLayout);

    // <-- HERE
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor, 0));    
}
```

I think you need to access [R.styleable.TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.styleable.html#TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor) to get what you want. I don't have the possibility right now to test if and how it works but I hope this helps you a bit.

**Update**

I tried this at home and it seems to work. I used this code in the `onCreate()` method of my Activity

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(null, R.styleable.TabLayout, 0, R.style.Widget_Design_TabLayout);
// returns -16738680 in my case which is the accentColor
int color = a.getColor(R.styleable.TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor, 0);
```

But I saw, that `R.styleable.TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor` just links to the `accentColor`. Maybe this is the better way to get what you want.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- other items -->
</style>
```

Comment: Great, I will try this solution and will tell you if it works.

Comment: @AtifRehman Did you have the chance to try this? I'm interested by myself if this works :)

Comment: I was stuck in giving update of an app I am working on, will try it as soon as possible. Thanks for the response will let you know very soon.