# How to change color icon in TabLayout in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
tabLayout.AddTab(tabLayout.NewTab().SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Home24),true);
```

I want :

default color of icon is #F3F3F3(unclicked)

default color of icon is #00000(clicked).

Comment: Note the following answers - [David_E answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30904139/4059570) - [Tako answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33230289/4059570)

Answer (score 3):

First, create a color selector in `Resources/drawable/tab_icon_color.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#000000" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="#F3F3F3" />
</selector>
```

To get a `ColorStateList` from that xml:

```
var tabIconColors = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop
                        ? Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Drawable.home_tab_icon_color, Activity.Theme)
                        : Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Drawable.home_tab_icon_color);
```

Then, for each tab:

```
var tab = tabLayout.NewTab().SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Whatever);

// we wrap the icon to support API < 21
var iconWrap = DrawableCompat.Wrap(tab.Icon);
DrawableCompat.SetTintList(iconWrap, tabIconColors);
tab.SetIcon(iconWrap);

tabLayout.AddTab(tab);
```

Results (with different colors though):

[image]

Comment: should be marked as answer, works perfectly. The image example uses #FFFFFF for selected and the material guidelines 70% of that color, which is #B3B3B3.