# Android TabPageIndicator remove small line

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I made such TabPageIndicator, how can i remove the small line. Used [viewpagerindicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)

[image]

Comment: Show your layout code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using android support libs for [**Tabs**](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) intead of third party library.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In code you can setup tabs in one line of code

```
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

And then set tab indicator height to 0 and color to tablayoutcolor to make them disappear

```
 TabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int height)
```

For the color:

```
TabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int color)
```

You can find complete example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) and thread related to tab color [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height)