# TabLayout tab background is not changing onclick

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

I am trying to change background color of **tab in tablayout** , i have tried several suggested methods on SO ,

but unfortunately they are working only **onSwipe** tab change , not **onClick**

Here are some questions i have been following [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230289/5896744) , [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904139/5896744)

**My Attempt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab1_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab1_background_unselected" android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

- Set `app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg"`
- In tab_bg.xml my code looks something as given above

  ---

**Note:** i am not using **TabHost** , i'm just using tabLayout with viewpager , so tabHost answers are not helpful for me

Comment: try adding `<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab1_background_selected" android:state_activated="true" />` to your selector

Comment: Just tried it @hrskrs not working